# Talbe row value (MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some difficulties with a table.

I got a site that users can't send in 6 different answer to lessons.

After the user has done that, he can correct 3 others answers.

When the user have delivered 1 and corrected 3 of same `modulid` he will have the `modulid` approved.

The table I have contains these columns:

> username, modulid, correctedby, answer, result

It the correcting part that I'm having problems with.If one have corrected one, it will get  row value 1, and if 2 user has corrected it, value changes to 2, etc..

Can I somehow set a table row to have a default value `NULL` and contain the value to be from 1 to 3?

Then some one try to add something the 4 times, i want to output a message like " it full"(and you wont get it as option for searching for `modulid` to correct)

Can i write like this:

```
$sql  = "SELECT  modulid=1 FROM tablename  WHERE correctedby=1-3 NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: `SELECT modulid=1` & `correctedby=1-3 NULL` ? Do not make your own syntax. RTFM !

Comment: i know that is not correct, it was most for explaining my dilemma. Im sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT modulid FROM tablename
WHERE modulid = 1
AND (correctedby IN (1,2,3) OR correctedby IS NULL)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

But your result will either be:

```
modulid
=======
1
```

or no rows returned.

You should control / filter the input before inserting into database (e.g. check if the database is "full", based on your designed criteria)